# Entity Framework Core many-to-many relation - getting error "Invalid column name 'id'"

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm doing a triple many-to-many relationship in the same relationship table in Entity Framework Core.

The certificate, language and candidate entities are related to each other from many-to-many in the `CandidateLanguageCertificationLanguage` relationship table.

The database tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE candidato.Candidato
(
        ID_CANDIDATO  int ,
        NOMBRE  VARCHAR(50) ,
        PRIMARY KEY(ID_CANDIDATO)
);

CREATE TABLE candidato.Idiomaa
(
        ID_IDIOMA  int ,
        NOMBRE  VARCHAR(50) ,
        PRIMARY KEY(ID_IDIOMA)
);

CREATE TABLE candidato.CertificadoIdiomaa
(
        ID_CERTIFICADO_IDIOMA  int,
        NOMBRE  VARCHAR(50),
        PRIMARY KEY(ID_CERTIFICADO_IDIOMA)
);

CREATE TABLE candidato.CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa
(
        ID_CANDIDATO  int,
        ID_IDIOMA  int,
        ID_CERTIFICADO_IDIOMA  int, 
        PRIMARY KEY(ID_CANDIDATO, ID_IDIOMA, ID_CERTIFICADO_IDIOMA),
        FOREIGN KEY (ID_CANDIDATO) REFERENCES candidato.Candidato (id_candidato),
        FOREIGN KEY (ID_IDIOMA) REFERENCES candidato.Idiomaa (ID_IDIOMA),
        FOREIGN KEY (ID_CERTIFICADO_IDIOMA) REFERENCES candidato.CertificadoIdiomaa (ID_CERTIFICADO_IDIOMA) 
);
```

The relationships established in the context through Fluent API are:

```
builder.Entity<CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa>().ToTable("CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa", "candidato");
builder.Entity<CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa>().HasKey(cici => new { cici.IdCandidato, cici.IdIdioma, cici.IdCertificadoIdioma });
builder.Entity<CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa>().Property(cici => cici.IdCandidato).HasColumnName("Id_Candidato");
builder.Entity<CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa>().Property(cici => cici.IdIdioma).HasColumnName("Id_Idioma");
builder.Entity<CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa>().Property(cici => cici.IdCertificadoIdioma).HasColumnName("Id_Certificado_Idioma");

builder.Entity<CertificadoIdiomaa>().ToTable("CertificadoIdiomaa", "candidato");
builder.Entity<CertificadoIdiomaa>().HasKey(ci => ci.Id);
builder.Entity<CertificadoIdiomaa>().Property(ci => ci.Id).HasColumnName("Id_Certificado_Idioma").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
builder.Entity<CertificadoIdiomaa>().Property(ci => ci.Nombre).HasColumnName("Nombre");

builder.Entity<Idiomaa>().ToTable("Idiomaa", "candidato");
builder.Entity<Idiomaa>().HasKey(i => i.Id);
builder.Entity<Idiomaa>().Property(i => i.Id).HasColumnName("Id_Candidato").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
builder.Entity<Idiomaa>().Property(i => i.Nombre).HasColumnName("Nombre");

builder.Entity<Candidato>().ToTable("Candidato", "candidato");
builder.Entity<Candidato>().HasKey(i => i.Id);
builder.Entity<Candidato>().Property(i => i.Id).HasColumnName("Id_Candidato").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
builder.Entity<Candidato>().Property(i => i.Nombre).HasColumnName("Nombre");

builder.Entity<CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa>()
       .HasOne(cici => cici.CertificadoIdioma)
       .WithMany(cei => cei.CandidatosIdiomasCertificacionesIdiomaas)
       .HasForeignKey(cf => cf.IdCertificadoIdioma);
builder.Entity<CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa>()
       .HasOne(cici => cici.Candidato)
       .WithMany(c => c.CandidatosIdiomasCertificacionesIdiomaas)
       .HasForeignKey(cici => cici.IdCandidato);
builder.Entity<CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa>()
       .HasOne(cici => cici.Idioma)
       .WithMany(cei => cei.CandidatosIdiomasCertificacionesIdiomaas)
       .HasForeignKey(cf => cf.IdIdioma);
```

The models are:

```
public class Idiomaa
{
        #region propiedades
        public int Id { get; internal set; }
        public string Nombre { get; internal set; }
        //public ICollection<CandidatoIdiomaa> CandidatosIdiomas { get; internal set; }
        public ICollection<CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa> CandidatosIdiomasCertificacionesIdiomaas { get; internal set; }
        #endregion
}

public class CertificadoIdiomaa
{
            public int Id{ get; internal set; }
            public string Nombre { get; internal set; }
            public ICollection<CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa> CandidatosIdiomasCertificacionesIdiomaas { get; internal set; }
}

public class CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa
{
        #region propiedades
        public int IdCandidato { get; internal set; }
        public int IdIdioma { get; internal set; }
        public int IdCertificadoIdioma { get; internal set; }
        public CertificadoIdiomaa CertificadoIdioma { get; internal set; }
        public Candidato Candidato { get; internal set; }
        public Idiomaa Idioma { get; internal set; }
        #endregion
}

public class Candidato 
{
        #region propiedades
        public int Id { get; internal set; }
        public string CorreoElectronico { get; internal set; }
        #endregion
}
```

The query I wrote is:

```
contexto.Where(certificadoIdioma => certificadoIdioma.Nombre.Contains(filtro))
        .Include(ci => ci.CandidatosIdiomasCertificacionesIdiomaas)
        .ThenInclude(cici => cici.Idioma).ToList();
```

The error I get:

> Invalid column name 'Id_Candidato'
>   Invalid column name 'Id_Candidato'

The funny thing is that if I change the include of the query to candidate it works perfect:

```
contexto.Where(certificadoIdioma => certificadoIdioma.Nombre.Contains(filtro))
        .Include(ci => ci.CandidatosIdiomasCertificacionesIdiomaas)
        .ThenInclude(cici => cici.candidato).ToList();
```

The tables have been made by a DBA, I am a programmer and I cannot modify the database, I know that you could make the relations in several tables instead of one, your reasons will be, that's another story. I am sure that in Entity Framework Core this can be done but I do not know how, I suspect that I have made a mistake when setting up the relationships in Fluent API, but I have been reviewing it for hours and nothing ...

Could someone take a look at it?

Thank you so much guys.

regards

Comment: Just a typo? When you start setting up `builder.Entity<Candidato>()` - the following lines are all `builder.Entity<Idiomaa>()`..... shouldn't those also be `builder.Entity<Candidato>()` ???

Comment: @Shabuu Seethal you are missing int keyword in your class

Comment: You are right, this is a copy/ paste error. I have edited coded.

Comment: The error is the same. Invalid column name 'Id_Candidato'

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **int** keyword:

```
public class Idiomaa
{
        #region propiedades
        public Id { get; internal set; }    here int keyword is missing
        public string Nombre { get; internal set; }
        //public ICollection<CandidatoIdiomaa> CandidatosIdiomas { get; internal set; }
        public ICollection<CandidatoIdiomaCertificacionIdiomaa> CandidatosIdiomasCertificacionesIdiomaas { get; internal set; }
        #endregion
}
```

```
public Id { get; internal set; }    here int keyword is missing
```

Comment: You are right, this is a copy/ paste error. I have edited coded.

Comment: The error is the same."Invalid column name 'Id_Candidato"

Comment: @Shabuu Seethal  try the ```[key]``` data annotation on your model class

Comment: I can only use fluent api, data notation is forbidden in my project